# What is the root of first class object in programming languages?

Tags: logic, computer-science, lambda-calculus, formal-systems

What is the root of "[first class object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)" of programming languages? (Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245192/what-are-first-class-objects)

Does it come from logics, lambda calculus or some other formal systems and the languages used in these formal systems? Thanks.

Comment: The term comes from Strachey's pioneering work in programming language semantics that you can read about by following a link in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen that you cite. Please go and read Strachey and then come back if you have further questions.